# How to query entities by future dates with Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

This is my scenario. I have an entity called Appointment. It is created like this -

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Entity
@Table(name = "appointment")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Appointment extends AbstractAuditingEntity{

    @JsonFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
    private Date appointmentDate;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private AppointmentStatus appointmentStatus;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Patient patient;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "doctor_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Doctor doctor;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String appointCancelReason;
}
```

In the implementation, an appointment can be booked by a patient. A patient can specify any future date when booking for the appointment.
Now I need to write a Spring Data JPA query to display a list of upcoming appointments for a doctor. My thought process is to use `findAppointmentByAppointmentDateIsAfter()` because I feel all the appointments booked on a future date should make a list of upcoming appointments. Any better suggestion will be appreciated. Or kindly show me how best I can use `findAppointmentByAppointmentDateIsAfter()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Spring Data JPA method name [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation),

you can provide a method with the following signature in the spring JPA repository which you extend

```
List<Appointment> findByAppointmentDateAfter(Date date)
```

and it will be automatically be implemented by Spring to do what you want it to do. Then you just have to call it and pass as parameter the date that you intend to filter by.

Comment: This works but returns only appointments after todays date. Does not track a period/time after current date and time

Comment: `findAppointmentsByDoctorAndAppointmentDateAfter(Doctor doctor, Date date)`

Comment: @SteveOluwatosinOlaleye You say `This works but returns only appointments after todays date. Does not track a period/time after current date and time` This is because you have declared `@JsonFormat(pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")` meaning you don't care about time here

Comment: Thanks. This is not the case. Removing it does not make any difference.

Comment: @SteveOluwatosinOlaleye use debug and use an actual Date that contains time. Probably you still have data that don't have time at all

Comment: @Spring functionality `After` works, it is the data that you have that cause this

Comment: Yes `After` works. But only for days order than today. It does not work for a time today after current time

Comment: @SteveOluwatosinOlaleye that's what I am explaining to you. It works for comparison of time as well but either your objects do not contain time or it contains some false time and you misread it

Comment: Thanks  
Panagiotis Bougioukos. It is working now

Comment: @SteveOluwatosinOlaleye please accept the answer if it helped you solve the issue

Comment: Ok, but how do I go about that?

Comment: @SteveOluwatosinOlaleye you just click on the tick of the answer to mark it as accepted.